# How do i remove '/' from the path without using string manipulation and using pathlib

Tags: python-3.x, path, pathlib

I have a path say  `path = pathlib.Path('/home/user/dir1/some.txt')`

```
>>> path
PosixPath('/home/user/dir1/some.txt')
```

How do i get only `home/user/dir1` and not the 1st '/' ?

If i use path.parent it will give me

```
>>> path.parent
PosixPath('/home/user/dir1')
```

How do i eliminate the 1st `'/'` from the path ?

I don't want to do any string manipulation like `lstrip('/')`
Is there any way to do this using **pathlib.Path** ?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to):

```
from pathlib import Path

some_path = Path("/home/user/dir1/some.txt")
print(some_path.relative_to("/"))
```

or

```
root = Path("/")
print(some_path.relative_to(root))
```

or even

```
print(some_path.relative_to(some_path.root))
```

all of these return `PosixPath('home/user/dir1/some.txt')` (and print `home/user/dir1/some.txt`).

Comment: thanks @hiroProtagonist,the solution provided is working for me. Thanks for quick response.